# curl bash shell disable floating point transformation on

Tags: bash, shell, curl, floating-point

I've been trying to get an response over http with curl. The response is in json format and contains numbers

when I get the reply there are fields with numeric values but the floating point has been changed as follows:

```
"value": 2.7123123E7 instead of just "value": 27123123
```

why is this happening and how I can disable it? I do not want to parse the file second time and do the change, but just disable this behavior. For example my web browser where I submit the same query does not has this behavior but I cannot use my browser because the data I want to gather (response) is very big and it stucks :S

Thank you

Comment: `2.7123123E7`==`27123123`. Perhaps your server is looking at the `user-agent` or your browser side script is doing something intelligent to convert `2.7123123E7` to `27123123`.

Comment: The thing is that I do not want this transformation, is it possible to elaborate more on the user-agent maybe I can override some options in the curl request. Thanks again

Comment: This seems to be a server issue; any answer would require detailed knowledge about what it is doing and what, if any, configuration is allowed in the URLs that it accepts.

Comment: If the **literal** value you are getting back from the server differs when you use `curl` versus when you use your browser then you need to find out what flags/etc. the browser is sending that curl isn't (or vice versa). But I think it might be more likely that javascript is simply converting the number for display in the browser when used in a page (as opposed to displayed raw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `jq` will do this for you if you want a simple filter to convert the notation:

```
$ echo '{"value":2.7123123E7}' | jq '.'
{
  "value": 27123123
}
```

See the [manual](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for more info. So, a simple parsing would just be to pipe the output of `curl` through `jq`.